# Gorilla Mux for sub path Routing

Tags: go, httphandler, gorilla, servemux

I have the following routes:

```
router.Methods("POST").Path("/my_post_01").HandlerFunc(myHandler1)
router.Methods("GET").Path("/my_get_01").HandlerFunc(myHandler2)

router.Methods("POST").Path("/my_post_02").HandlerFunc(myHandler3)
router.Methods("GET").Path("/my_get_02").HandlerFunc(myHandler4)

router.Methods("POST").Path("/my_post_03").HandlerFunc(myHandler5)
router.Methods("GET").Path("/my_get_03").HandlerFunc(myHandler6)

router.Methods("POST").Path("/my_post_04").HandlerFunc(myHandler7)
router.Methods("GET").Path("/my_get_04").HandlerFunc(myHandler8)

router.Methods("POST").Path("/my_post_05").HandlerFunc(myHandler9)
router.Methods("GET").Path("/my_get_05").HandlerFunc(myHandler10)
```

As I have more and more routes, it gets harder to manage.

I want to do something like:

```
router.Path("/my/*").HandleFunc(mypackage.RegisterHandler)
```

with all handlers being separated in another package

Is there any way that I can match those paths in a separate package?

Thanks,

Comment: ...have you tried what you put here? There is nothing stopping you from passing a `http.HandlerFunc` that resides in another package to your router...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a package for your router then import said package and add your routes.

Router

```
package router

var Router = mux.NewRouter()
// handle "/my/" routes
var MyRouter = Router.PathPrefix("/my").Subrouter()
```

another package

```
import "/path/to/router"

func init() {
    router.MyRouter.Methods("POST").Path("/post_01").HandlerFunc(myHandler1)
}
```

In main

```
import "/path/to/router"

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", router.Router)

    //...
}
```

Comment: Then how do I avoide prefixing `my_` to every handler?

Comment: @cvxv31431asdas I added a subrouter example.  It does not let you add `my_` but it does allow for a path prefix of `/my/`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot better if you could extract `id` from the request URL and handle it in a generic handler.

Actually, it is not far from where you are right now, modify you router like this:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Methods("POST").HandleFunc("/articles/{article_id:[0-9]+}", ArticlePostHandler)
```

`article_id` is the parameter name and `[0-9]+` is the regexp to match it.

And in the `ArticlePostHandler` (you could import it from another package), use `mux.Vars` to get the id, like this:

```
func ArticlePostHandler(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   articleId := mux.Vars(req)["article_id"]
   // do whatever you want with `articleId`
}
```

Document: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux